# Faced error of No overload matches this call in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was creating React project and faced and I have a form component and it has onSubmit event which shows an error of "No overload matches this call". Here is the code:  `<StyledForm onSubmit={this.handleSave}>{children}</StyledForm>`.

> Here onSubmit shows an error of No overload matches this call.
>   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick &
>   StyledComponentProps, context?: any): ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
>       Type '(authorizeRequired?: boolean | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: FormEvent) => any'.
>         Types of parameters 'authorizeRequired' and 'event' are incompatible.
>           Type 'FormEvent' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
>             Type 'FormEvent' is not assignable to type 'true'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren & StyledComponentProps>, context?: any):
>   ReactElement ReactElement Component<...>)> | null) | (new (props:
>   any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following
>   error.
>       **Type '(authorizeRequired?: boolean | undefined) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: FormEvent) => any'.ts(2769)
>   StyledForm.tsx(25, 5): The expected type comes from property
>   'onSubmit' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   Pick & StyledComponentProps'
>   StyledForm.tsx(25, 5): The expected type comes from property
>   'onSubmit' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   Pick & StyledComponentProps &
>   { children?: ReactNode; }'**

The code of handleSave:

```
handleSave = (authorizeRequired?: boolean) => {
        const { mode, isNewDataSource, form, saveHandler } = this.props;
        const data = mergeAll<any>([
            form.value,
            {
                isNew: mode === DSFormMode.create,
                isNewDataSource,
            },
        ]);

        saveHandler(data, authorizeRequired);
    };
```

The code for StyledForm:

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
    children: ReactNode;
    onSubmit?(event: FormEvent); // here it shows error of 'onSubmit', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type
}
const StyledFormRoot = ({ classes, children, onSubmit = identity }: Props) => (
    <form className={classes.container} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {children}
    </form>
);
export const StyledForm = withStyles(styles)(StyledFormRoot);
```

If something is not clear please let me know

Answer (score 3):

changing that onSubmit on the interface to `(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)` should do it

with a `ctrl + click` on the onSubmit you can see what is it that is expected to return

I always find myself in trouble with types too :/